# VB.NET - MVC ModelState.IsValid is always true

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, validation

I'm looking for an extra pair of eyes on this, I have followed this article http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx on MVC validation.

Although its an older article most concepts appear to be valid. Everything works in C# however my project is in VB.NET so I have applied a very simple version in VB.NET but when the ModelState.IsValid is checked it ALWAYS returns True even though the title field is empty. Can anyone see where I am going wrong? Many Thanks in advance.

Controller:

```
    Namespace ValidationTest
    Public Class FriendsController
        Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller
```

```
    '
    ' GET: /Friends

    Function Index() As ActionResult
        Return View()
    End Function

    Function Create() As ActionResult
        Dim friendToCreate As New Person()
        Return View(friendToCreate)
    End Function

    <HttpPost> _
    Function Create(friendToCreate As Person) As ActionResult
        If (ModelState.IsValid) Then

        End If
        Return View(friendToCreate)
    End Function
End Class
```

End Namespace

Create View:

```
@ModelType ValidationTest.Person
@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Create"
End Code

@Using Html.BeginForm()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(True)

    @
        Person

        
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Title)
        
        
            @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Title)
        

        
            
        
    
End Using


    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")


@Section Scripts
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
End Section
```

Class:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
Public Class Person

   <Required()> _
   <StringLength(50)> _
   Private _title As String
    Public Property Title() As String
        Get
            Return _title
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _title = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model is missing the `RequiredAttribute`. You also don't need to define a property with an underlying private variable, it is generated by the compiler automatically.

```
<Required(AllowEmptyStrings:=False, ErrorMessage:="Enter the title")>
Public Property Title As String
```

Comment: Thanks, the <Required()> attribute is actually in there but the editor has stripped it out, I will update the code now.

Comment: "You also don't need to define a property with an underlying private variable," - Removing the private variable means that the validation now works. Thanks very much. Do you know why this is the case?

Comment: You have placed the `RequiredAttribute` on the private variable instead of the property. I think when you place it on the property it will work as well.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, many thanks for the help on this, that's been noted. I'm C# dev and never use the private variables but this is on an existing project and has has thrown me. Cheers again that's great!